# Can we change the values in application.properties file at runtime in spring boot? and how?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to change the value of the key which is present in the spring boot's application.properties file based on whatever request that we are receiving to our web service.

Is there a way to change application.properties file at runtime?

Comment: You can override it from an environment variable, if that's what you mean? That won't be per-request, though. Perhaps some context would help?

Comment: Actually, I'm enabling the access logs for my web service. I have enabled it, now I need to change its pattern string because each request is having different request ID and I want to capture this in the access logs. For that, I need to pass the request ID every time to access log's pattern string hence I want to change the key's value in application.properties file. Hope this will help you with my scenario.

Comment: Not really; why does that change the *pattern* of the string? You should be able to have one pattern and put different *values* in it.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, is there a way to achieve this?